# build.sbt it:test is not working for integration testing junit cases

Tags: java, scala, junit, sbt, integration-testing

I am new to scala,
junit test cases are not running in integration test.

folder structure

```
src
  |- it
  |- main
  |- test
```

when i do `sbt test` all the test cases in "test" folder is executed fine,
but when i do `it:test`

```
[error] No such setting/task
[error] it:test
[error]
```

where `it` folder contain Tester.scala

```
        package RegexExtractor
        import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
        import org.junit.Test
            
class  Tester   {
             @Test
     def testAdd1(): Unit = {
      val result = 2 + 4
      assertTrue(result == 6)
      System.out.println("Test final Passed")
     }
    }
    }
```

i added in build.sbt

```
lazy val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies += scalatest % "it,test",

    // other settings here

  )
```

Please help me for running integration test

Answer (score 0):

In SBT support for JUnit is provided by [junit-interface](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface):

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.github.sbt" % "junit-interface" % "0.13.2" % Test
```

Add `junit-interface` to your integration test configuration:

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
    libraryDependencies += "com.github.sbt" % "junit-interface" % "0.13.2" % "it,test"
  ...
  )
```

[Check some usage patterns for junit-interface](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface#usage).

In your case for `it` to run all integration test:

```scala
IntegrationTest/ test
```